# Node Mysql queries queue but never execute

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I loop over some directories and then the files in them. I process the files by directory and then try to add the processed results into MySQL.
I call conn.query('INSERT QUERY HERE') and it seems to continue on but the query never runs on the server. If I tell it to just process one directory and wait till the end it will run the queries but I can't have it continue to store all the queries in memory till the end of the script or node will fail out due to mem cap. I have tried everything I can think of to try and force the queued queries to run but no luck.

Here is an example of my code

```
dirs.forEach(function(dir){
  var data = [];
  var connection = mysql.createConnection(conConfig);
  files.forEach(function(file){
    //do some processing on files push into data array 
    //creating array of objects
  });
  data.forEach(function(record){
    connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLE SET ?', record);
  });
  connection.end();
});
```

The code will just continue to loop over the directories without ever sending the query to mysql. I know it will work by limiting the code to just run on one directory and it will runt he queries once the one directory is processed but not if I let it run on all directories.

I have tried using mysql pooling as well with no luck. The
`pool.on('enqueue' function...` will fire but never send it over to the server.

edit:
So I tried calling the script with a for loop from bash to call every dir name individually and all records were loaded. I'm dumbfounded as to why a mysql connection is never established in my orig example.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your values within each loop are good? Try adding a callback function as third parameter to `connection.query()` and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: I have, I just put some basic code up there to give an idea of the structure. As mentioned if I just run on one directory (no matter which one) it will work every time. But yes there is an anon funct  to throw err if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact an async issue. There does not seem to be any way to force queued queries to execute without stopping the current running process. I had to use the async module in order to make my code work.

@luksch connection.end() will not close the connection till all queued queries are finished. I did use his iteration method to make the callback though.

Here is how I did it.

```
var async = require('async');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(conConfig);
var dirs = fs.readdirSync('./rootdirectory');

async.eachSeries(dirs,function(dir,callback){
  var data = [];
  files.forEach(function(file){
    //do some processing on files push into data array 
    //creating array of objects
  });
  var qCount = data.length;
  data.forEach(function(record){
    connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLE SET ?', record, function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
      qCount--
      if(qCount === 0) { callback(true); }
    });
  });
  function(){ connection.end(); }
});
```

This will iterate over the directories and queue all the queries and then force the queries to be run till all directories have been processed then call the final function to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript calls the mysql query asynchronously. That means the connection will likely be be closed before all insert queries are finished.

What you can do is to use the callbacks that the query function provides:

```
var qCnt = array.length;
var connection = mysql.createConnection(conConfig);
connection.connect();
array.forEach(function(record){
  connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLE SET ?', record, function(err){
     if (err) throw err;

     qCnt--;
     if (qCnt == 0){
          connection.end();
     }
  });
});
```

This solution is not ideal, since all the insert queries are fired regardless of your database connection limit etc. you may want to fire the next insert only after the former is done. This is also possible with some tricks.

Comment: I have tried this approach and it did not change the behavior. What I don't understand is why the mysql lib waits till the script is done to even establish a connection to the mysql server. I know it is calling the query command because I can pull the var from it and log out the query string.

Comment: According to the npm modul documentation for mysql, you should to call `connection.connect();` after creating the connection. I just added this in my answer. (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: You don't it says directly below that "However, a connection can also be implicitly established by invoking a query:" and calling connect does not establish a connection. Also the query callback is never called.

Comment: Hmm... you are right. I was just checking the beginning of the docs... however, I can use the mysql module in node without problems. I use connection pools however and I usually force sequential calling of the INSERTS outside the queue of the mysql module though javascript flow control. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495594/basic-flow-control-in-javascript

Comment: I tried using a pooled connection setup but even that did not help.